# How to call custom method in ruby on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to create a custom method, which I have defined in my **questions_controller.rb** file, as so:

```
def self.ping
  @question = Question.first
  @question.update(:amplify => @question.amplify + 1)
end
```

Now the problem is how do I call this method? Do I need to define a route first? How can I reference this from the console?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with `ping` method?

Comment: Whenever the `ping` method is called, I want to reference the first `Question` and update it's attribute by +1. So `:amplify` is 1 at the beginning and then each time the method is called, `:amplify` is incremented by 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest to move it to your model:

**question.rb**

```
def self.ping
  question = Question.first
  question.update(:amplify => question.amplify + 1)
end
```

and define custom route, **routes.rb**

```
post '/ping' => 'questions#ping', as: 'ping'
```

**questions_controller.rb**

```
def ping
   Question.ping
end
```

then you can reference it from console:

```
Question.ping
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read this http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

class Foo

def self.bar

```
puts 'class method'
```

end

def baz

```
puts 'instance method'
```

end

end

Foo.bar # => "class method"

Foo.baz # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘baz’ for Foo:Class

Foo.new.baz # => instance method

Foo.new.bar # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘bar’

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
question.update(:amplify => question.amplify + 1)
```

You can use

```
question.increment!(:amplify)
```